# Can I add a double quote inside a variable in PHP when it starts with "\n"?

Tags: php, variables, newline

UPDATE !!!

It seems that the website I used to test my code has issues and therefore I had problem with executing my thing. I still leave this post up, so someone else, with similar problem can learn something.

website to avoid: http://phptester.net

---

---

---

ORIGINAL POST !!!

I want to add a string to my variable that uses a double qouted word. Is that possible? I only get error.

```
FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'Old' (T_STRING) on line number 4
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$var = "name: ";
$biography = "\n I'm Robert and I came from \"Old\" Europe.";

echo $biography;
?>
```

I was checking it on this website:

http://phptester.net

It must be smg to do with the new line character in the beginning, or perhaps its not even possible to add double qouted words to a variable. I am not sure.
Your help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Yes, [that works fine](https://3v4l.org/iHnvO). What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi! I get this: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'Old' (T_STRING) on line number 4

Comment: That website is broken. Don't use it. It keeps stripping the backslashes.

Comment: Ok thanks it makes sense now.

Comment: If you still want to use the phptester.net website then you must use double backslashes: `$biography = "\n I'm Robert and I came from \\"Old\\" Europe.";`. Of course, you don't need doing it when coding, but only for testing purposes on that website